# Symfony - ArrayCollection - Update or Create

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

- Symfony 4.3
- Goal : import a CSV listing employees/company with doctrine and save it into the DB.

I have the Entity company :

```
<?php

// src/Entity/Company.php
class Company
{

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Employee", mappedBy="company")
    */
    private $employees;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->employees = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getEmployees()
    {
        return $this->employees;
    }
```

and the Employee entity :

```
<?php

// src/Entity/Employee.php
class Employee
{

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Company", inversedBy="employees")
    */
    private $company;

    public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->company;
    }

    public function setCompany(?Company $company)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
        return $this;
    }
```

Below is my loop for each line of the CSV being imported :

```
<?php

    // $csv = array made from the CSV file
    // e.g. $csv[0]['employee_name'] = "John Doe"
    // e.g. $csv[0]['employee_mail'] = "john.doe@bmw.com"
    // e.g. $csv[0]['employee_company_name'] = "BMW"
    // e.g. $csv[0]['employee_company_id'] = 77

    foreach($csv as $key => $value)
    {
        if($company = $this->em->getRepository(Company::class)->find($value['employee_company_id']))
        {
            // if the employee doest not exist, create it
            // IN MY TESTS, HERE IS MY PROBLEM
            // DON'T KNOW HOW TO LOOP INSIDE THE EMPLOYEES LIST USING the MAIL
            if ($company->getEmployees()->contains($value['employee_mail']))
            {
                // This employee for this company exists, let's update it
            }
            else
            {
                // This employee for this company does not exist, let's create it
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Create the company
        }
```

I don't know how to loop inside the company employees list, in order to decide if I have to edit (employee already exists) or create a new employee. Maybe I should not use the ArrayCollection::contains method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the naive approach would be to just look in the employee repository.

```
$employee = $em->getRepository(Employee::class)->findOneBy([
    'company' => $company, 
    'email' => $value['employee_mail'],
]);
if($employee) {
    // exists -> update
} else {
    // create
}
```

Depending on the company-employee-ratio, it might be better to cycle through the company's employees instead:

```
$employee = null;
foreach($company->getEmployees() as $_employee) {
    if($_employee->getEmail() == $value['employee_mail']) {
         $employee = $_employee;
         break; // short circuit the loop
    }
}
// rest is the same
```

If there are is *very large number of employees* in your csv and/or the database, it *might* be even better to skip the ORM alltogether and go straight to the database instead. Otherwise, you might want to clear the entity manager once in a while, if you have a huge database / csv.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I can't use your first solution because inside the Employee database table, the employees are linked to companies with the `company_id` field. I don't have that integer from the CSV. But your advice to skip ORM in case of big file is interresting, thanks for the tip !

Comment: @deferre_mario_po but you have that `$company = ...->find()` call, and with that, the company. so unless your $company is something completely different, this should work

Answer (score 1):

As `Employees` is an Doctrine ArrayCollection, you can use the `exists` method on it. This method accepts a closure as argument which loops over all elements in the collection and returns `true` when the condition matches.

```php
if ($company->getEmployees()->exists(function ($key, Employee $employee) use ($value) {
    return $employee->getEmail() === $value['employee_mail'];
})) {
    // Employee exists, update
} else {
    // Employee does not exist
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to create/update the record right away, you can do the following. This returns the `Employee` if it exists, or create a new `Employee` object if it doesn't

```php
$employee = $company
    ->getEmployees()
    ->filter(function (Employee $employee) use ($value) {
        return $employee->getEmail() === $value['employee_mail'];
    })
    ->first() ?? new Employee();
```

Comment: I tested your solution, an error for the first line says "App\Utils\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Entity\Employee, integer given". I guess the problem comes from the $value var (which is an array...) ?

Comment: My bad! I've updated the code. The first argument in the closure is the index, the second argument is the value

Comment: the only caveat is: even though the employee exists, you now have to get the Employee entity ;o/ (it's exactly this reason, why I didn't use this approach)

Comment: I've updated the code to include a alternative scenario still utilizing `ArrayCollection` methods

Answer (score 0):

You should store first your list of employees :

```
$employees = $company->getEmployees()
```

then you loop inside $employees :

```
foreach($employees as $employee ) //supposedly you have 'email' property
{
   if ($employee->getEmail() == $value['employee_mail'])
      {
         //your code here
      }
}
```

don't forget to add this :

```
*  @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Employee", mappedBy="company", fetch="EAGER")
```

**Update** :

```
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->where(':employee_mail OF a.emplyee_email')
    ->setParameter('employee_mail ', $value['employee_mail']);
    ->andWhere(':comapanyId MEMBER OF a.company_id');
    ->setParameter('comapanyId ', $value['employee_company_id']);
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute()
```

this will return null if the employee does not exist in the company, you should implement this as you need in your code.

Comment: Thank you, I tested it and your solution works. But 2 nested foreach + a big CSV ... not the best with performance I guess ?

Comment: By the way, it works without the `fetch="EAGER"` part !